# Regex - Replace html tags into double quotes

Tags: php, regex

How to replace

```
<option value="X"   >XXX</option>
<option value="Y"   >YYY</option>
<option value="ZZ"   >ZZZ</option>
```

I want to replace all option tag and i need to print like below

```
"XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ" ....
```

Not familiar with patterns. help me

Comment: parse the xml, and print the quoted text

Comment: Now obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/665800

Comment: Additional obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Comment: @scibuff : "parse the xml" can you explain this term in detail.

Comment: @gowri http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: And in your case if you're working with HTML, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the input will allways have this format, you can of course do it with regex. E.g.

```
<?php
$pattern = '/<\/?option[^>]*>\n?/';
$replacement = '"';
$subject = '<option value="X"   >XXX</option>
<option value="Y"   >YYY</option>
<option value="ZZ"   >ZZZ</option>';
$limit = -1;
$count = 0;
$result = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $limit, $count);
?>
```

printing the $result will output

```
"XXX""YYY""ZZZ"
```

if you want the additional spaces, you could run another replace and replace all `""` with `" "`.

To all potential downvoters. Dont be dogmatic about this. In many cases regexes do what is needed and they are just so much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should work..

```
$output = preg_replace("~<option[^>]*?>([^<>]*?)</option[^>]*?>~","$1",trim($html));
```